# How to use slice with if statement in Django?

Tags: django

The following code is causing error

```
 {% if product_category == 'Hotel' %}
         {% for p in post | slice:":12" %}
  ....
  ....
          {%endfor%}
{% endif %}
```

This code shows an error like:

```
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for p in post | slice:":12"
```

I want to limit the number of posts only for hotels, not for all the posts. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to remove the spaces. It should be `post|slice:":12"`

Comment: Thanks, that solve the error, but How can I limit the number of post for 'Hotel'? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Do it in Python code and pass it in the context.